# PHPMailer Update Issue (from 5.2.9 to 5.2.16)

Tags: email, phpmailer

PHPMailer works great, I've been using it for ages and it's pretty good. I have had version 5.2.9 on my server and have got the newer, 5.2.16 uploaded,

Now my sites have issues of:

> "SMTP Error: SMTP connect() failed."

I have added `$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;` and it gives me this:

```
2016-11-15 17:18:10 Connection: opening to localhost:25, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-11-15 17:18:10 Connection: opened
...
removed excess repetative lines
...

2016-11-15 17:18:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mail.servernetwork.co.uk Hello www.domain.co.uk [::1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250 HELP
2016-11-15 17:18:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-11-15 17:18:10 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2016-11-15 17:18:10 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 TLS go ahead
                                      "
2016-11-15 17:18:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2016-11-15 17:18:10 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2016-11-15 17:18:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-11-15 17:18:10 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
```

Nothing else has changed on the server. Reverting to PHPMailer Version 5.2.9 removes this error (and emails are sent ok).

I have also tried to update from 5.2.9 to 5.2.14 and 5.2.13 and the same error occurs. I have made no changes to the DNS and there are no DKIM or other identifiers set in the PHPmailer classes to allow version 5.2.9 but not 5.2.13 or 5.2.16 ones.

I'm using PHP Version 5.6.2.

Any clues as to why this is so?

The sending code:
(I realise the code is not the best but it's an older site I picked at random to test out PHPMailer 5.2.16)

```
$mail           = new PHPMailer();
//$mail->SMTPDebug=4;
$mail->Host     = "localhost";
$mail->WordWrap = 78;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->From     = $fromMail;
$mail->FromName = "Website: ".$name;
$mail->AddAddress($toEmail);
$mail->Subject = $member['bizname'] . " Enquiry";
$mail->Body    = $message;
if (!$mail->Send()) {  
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a day or so asking [various related](https://serverfault.com/questions/816873/exim-and-phpmailer-cant-accept-authentication-when-host-is-localhost) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786656/how-can-i-increase-the-speed-of-sending-secure-smtp-emails/40786927?noredirect=1#comment68801175_40786927), I found the answer lies with an update applied in PHPMailer 5.2.10.

I found that while my server is TLS certified, there seems to be a problem with using a `localhost` Host; possibly that PHPMailer may be trying to check the certificate applies to `localhost` domain, which of course it doesn't.

I found a solution to sending mail via Localhost now is therefore to disable auto-TLS with the following:

```
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
```

Using this all emails now send correctly.

---

**NOTE**

As [Bodi0 stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680087/3536236) using SMTPAuth is best practise, *however* I didn't realise that it is **unnessecary** for `localhost` mail servers as the authenticaton is implicit.

Comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40786927/3536236) to a related question about `->SMTPSecure` settings gives more details.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to initialize the settings is, note that you ***should*** set the `$mail->SMTPAuth = true`:

```
<?php
$mail->isSMTP();                          // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com';        // Specify main SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';     // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';               // SMTP password
//Only if you have SSL/TLS on your server 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                       // TCP port to connect to
...
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this on Monday. The code illustrated in my Q is a bit old and I'm aware it's not perfect (insecured SMTP), but this answer implies that PHPMailer won't send non-authed SMTP mail on versions above 5.2.9?

Comment: This actually depends not on PHPMailer itself, but on your mail server settings.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you, I would question that it's not a PHPMailer change as the only difference is PHPMailer version, so on version 5.2.9 I don't need SMTPAuth and on later versions I do, or at least, so it seems. I found a workaround was to replace `Host->"localhost";` with `Host->"hostname.co.uk";` which now works ok. (I am gradually adding SMTP auth as well but there's a lot of sites to apply this to so it's not instant).

Comment: I would suggest to add it as answer to your question, in order someone who has the same issue, to resolve it quickly.

Comment: Hi Bodi0, I won't set it as an answer yet, because it's not a complete answer, I [seem to have issues](http://serverfault.com/questions/816873/exim-and-phpmailer-cant-accept-authentication-when-host-is-localhost) using PHPMailer SMTP Authentication with `Host->Localhost`, the issue may well be Exim somewhere.