# How can I increase the speed of sending Secure SMTP emails?

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer, exim

I have a PHPMailer 5.2.16 on a server using Exim 4.87 which also has a TLS certificate for secured connections.

My PHP is thus:

```
class MailerSMTP extends PHPMailer {
    /***
     * Mailer for authenticated SMTP  emails using account mail system
     ***/
    public function __construct(){
        $this->AddReplyTo('...', '...');
        $this->setFrom('...', '...');
        $this->Host = "hostname.co.uk";
        $this->isSMTP();
        $this->Timeout = 20;

        $this->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $this->Port = "587";
        $this->Username = 'emailuser';
        $this->Password = 'emailpass';
    }
}
```

And this is obviously called on the script and populated with reciever and message, etc.

However the `SMTPSecure` aspect adds about **2 seconds** (or sometimes a bit more) on to the time taken to send the message. Currently this delay is on a single message sending, and I would *hope* (I think I read somewhere) that the SMTP secure would only need to be called once to send X number of messages to X number of recipients.

- While I accept this delay *might* be unavoidable to some extent, I would like some advice on to how to improve the efficiency of secured SMTP via this method?

---

Bonus Question:

- Am I correct in thinking that this delay would only occur once when this class is instantiated, regardless of the number of emails sent through it?

I would imagine I can do something like this:

```
$sender = new MailerSMTP();
$sender->subject ="hello";
$sender->Body = "message";
foreach($receiver as $row){
    $sender->addAddress($row['email']);
    $sender->send();
    $sender->clearAddresses();
}
```

Would this send all emails with only a 2 second `SMTPSecure` delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TLS adds some connection overhead. You can avoid it by submitting to a local mail server over SMTP without TLS - that's the fastest way to free up your script. It remains secure because it's not leaving the server, and you can configure your mail server to relay securely from there onwards.

You're nearly there on the multiple messages thing, but I recommend looking at the [mailing list example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) provided with PHPMailer. The most important thing when sending multiple messages in one go is to enable keepalive, which avoids repeating the connection overhead for each message.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the multiple mailings on the same object, it's a format I rarely use so wan'ted to double check it was the right approach. I will research the keep alive examples.

Comment: I had [a previous issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616539/phpmailer-update-issue-from-5-2-9-to-5-2-16) with using `Host->"localhost"` on PHPMailers above 5.2.9 but found that using a host name (even though it is a localhost) sidestepped this problem.

Comment: I have found that a significant delay is also caused by the `SMTPAuth` factor, as this doesn't work on `localhost` I need to provide a remote host so the server seems to be spending time trying to remotely connect to itself and authentication the SMTP sender that way.

Comment: You don't need auth when talking to localhost, and you can get your local mail server to authenticate when it's relaying. Why do you need a remote host? Does every message need different auth?

Comment: I think I've made a fundamental confusion there: Are you saying that if localhost then I don't need to use `->SMTPAuth` at all?

Comment: I understood (perhaps wrongly) that SMTPAuth was to authenticate that the mail came from a genuine mailbox, regardless of host being local or remote?

Comment: Yes. You only need to use auth to prove identity when the mail server is remote - if it's localhost (with no external inbound connection), auth can be implicit. You can still ultimately send through the same remote server using authentication, but you don't necessarily have to do that on the first hop - submit to localhost and get that local MTA to do the auth and send to remote, while your scripts are free to do other stuff. Look up how to configure your local MTA to do relaying, which is what this is.

Comment: Ahhh the penny drops! Many thanks for that valuable clarification.